# Pinescript 5 not showing line width 1px

Tags: tradingview-api

I have created an indicator in Pinescript 5 to show vertical New York midnight lines. However, the lines show fine when choosing 2, 3 or 4 pixel width, but when you choose 1 pixel it shows it 2 pixels wide.

Even if I set the width manually, the lines never go down to 1 pixel width. Any ideas why?

No matter what I do I just cannot get the lines to be 1 pixel wide.

[image]

Code below:

```
//@version=5
indicator('New York Midnights', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=4999)

styleOption = input.string("Solid", title="Line Style", options=["Solid", "Dotted", "Dashed"])
lineStyle = styleOption == "Solid" ? line.style_solid : styleOption == "Dotted" ? line.style_dotted : styleOption == "Dashed" ? line.style_dashed : line.style_solid

mondayWidthOption = input.int(4, options = [1,2,3,4],title="Monday Line Width")
mondayColorInput  = input.color(#000000,title="Monday Line Colour")

otherWidthOption = input.int(2, options = [1,2,3,4],title="Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri Line Width")
otherColorInput  = input.color(#000000,title="Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri Line Colour")

weekday = (dayofweek != dayofweek.saturday and dayofweek != dayofweek.sunday)

t1 = timestamp("GMT-5", year, month, dayofmonth, 00, 00, 00)

if weekday
    if dayofweek != dayofweek.monday
        line.new(t1,low,t1,high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, otherColorInput, style=lineStyle, width=otherWidthOption)
    else
        line.new(t1,low,t1,high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, mondayColorInput, style=lineStyle, width=mondayWidthOption)
```